# How do you configure a client to auto-answer within vLine?

Tags: webrtc, vline

What is the correct method for setting a [client](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Client) to auto answer with the [vLine API](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/) for WebRTC calls?

Comment: Turned out to be simpler than I thought.  You just have to call mediaSession.start() instead of showAcceptPrompt(mediaSession) in the onEnterIncoming handler.  My problem was that the event handlers were not being initialized correctly after I had modified the shell example.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment, it looks like you have figured this out. But for completeness and for future reference I will go ahead and answer.

To auto answer a call, all you have to do is call [`MediaSession.start()`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession#start) when an incoming call comes in, instead of throwing a prompt to the user.

Here is an example snippet:

```js
client.on('add:mediaSession', onAddMediaSession, self);

// Handle new media sessions
onAddMediaSession(event){
  var mediaSession = event.target;
  mediaSession.on('enterState:incoming', onIncoming, self);
},

// Handle new incoming calls and autoAccept
onIncoming(event){
  var mediaSession = event.target;

  // Auto Accept call instead of a prompt
  mediaSession.start();
}
```

Note that you can do this in your code even if you are using the [UI Widgets](https://vline.com/developer/docs/ui_widgets).